# pickle.load gives error : No module named 'smart_settings'

Tags: pickle

I tried simple code as below:

```
import pickle


with open("dataset.p", "rb") as f:
    pickle.load(f)
```

Then I executed this code. It gave me following error:

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'smart_settings'**

But there's no such package, right? Is there any other option to open .p file? Or anyone who knows why this happens?

Comment: Pickle files do not store any class or function definitions (if they did, it would be impossible to ever fix bugs or add features to those parts of the code).  Instead, they merely store references to the module and name of the definitions, and do an `import` of that module when unpickling the data.  Whoever made this file available to you has the responsibility of making any nonstandard modules it uses available as well, or the file is completely useless.

Comment: @jasonharper I tried to use the dataset which provided from https://github.com/martius-lab/CombOptNet .